# Deque emplace_back New Pointer To Object

Tags: c++, object, initialization, deque

I'm creating a new pointer to a new object and immediately push_front into a deque. I want to instead use emplace_front but am getting a compiler error.

My objects constructor requires 1 string argument.

```
std::deque<NetPacket*> q_IncomingPackets;

q_IncomingPackets.push_back(new NetPacket(std::string(uncompressed_data, retVal))));
q_IncomingPackets.emplace_back(std::string(uncompressed_data, retVal));
```

Following references from other websites I thought I could simply swap `push_back` for `emplace_back` but get the following error:

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'PeerNet::NetPacket *' PeerNet \vc\include\xmemory0    737
```

The references don't talk about using emplace when creating new pointers to objects, only concrete objects. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace_back) [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/emplace_back/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::deque::emplace_back` expects `Args&&... args` to construct `value_type`, which here is `NetPacket*`.

There is no way to construct `NetPacket*` from `std::string`, that's why the compiler error says.

Since your value type is `NetPacket*` (it's a raw pointer), there's no too much difference between `push_back` and `emplace_back`.